# Undeploy fails on Tomcat 7

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

I am trying to undeploy an application manually by going into Tomcat Manager and clicking on "Stop" and then on "Undeploy" but it gives me following message:

```
FAIL - Unable to delete [C:\apache-tomcat-7.0-standalone\webapps\istore-tax-service]. The continued presence of this file may cause problems.
```

Is this a bug in Tomcat 7?

Answer (score 0):

No. It is an application bug. Something in the application is opening a file and not closing it. That locks the file preventing it from being deleted.

Comment: I am using log4j to write logs to a file. I will try removing it and see it it works. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: If you are writing those logs to the web application directory I'd strongly encourage you to write them somewhere safer as that directory will be deleted when the application is undeployed.